# Latest() function gives, addPost(ModelName) matching query does not exist error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Why it is giving an error? it should give latest post..

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.
class addPost(models.Model):
    postId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/images", default="")
    content = models.TextField(default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "-date"
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    obj = addPost.objects.all().latest()
    print(obj.postId)
```

Comment: It means there are no records for the `addPost` model.

Comment: Of course my question is that why there is no record it should have the latest object..

Comment: because the corresponding database table is empty.